# How to split comma separated and & separated values in different columns in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
  volume       type_of_soil                     quantity
   2345        slit,coarse sand                 324.45
   1123.45     fine sand                        45 
   123.44      sand, sandstone, gravel, silt    567
   234         marine clay & hard strata        45
   232         category d                       55
```

My desired dataframe would be

```
   volume      type_of_soil_1   type_of_soil_2   type_of_soil_3   type_of_soil_4      quantity
   2345        slit              coarse sand     NA                NA                324.45
   1123.45     fine sand         NA              NA                NA                  45 
   123.44      sand              sandstone       gravel            silt                567
   234         marine clay       hard strata      NA               NA                  45
   232         category d        NA               NA               NA                  55
```

I want to seperate `comma and & seperated` values in `type_of_soil` column.

I have tried following,but it does not work

```
  max_length <- as.vector(count.fields(textConnection(df$type_of_soil), sep = ","))
  max_length <- max(max_length,na.rm = T)

  splitdat = do.call("rbind", strsplit(df$type_of_soil, ","))
  splitdat = data.frame(apply(splitdat, 2, as.character))
  names(splitdat) = paste("type_of_soil_", 1:max_length , sep = "")
```

Comment: You can try with `cSplit`  `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(df1, "type_of_soil", "[, ]")`

Comment: you can also try`separate` from `dplyr`

Comment: how are you handling the last entry? why is the part inside `()` lost?

Comment: I have updated the question